# New ManyToManyField object is not adding

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, many-to-many

I am building a BlogApp AND i made a feature of `Favorite Users` in the `ManyToManyField`.
It means `user_1` can add multiple favorite users in one field. I build a view to add users.

BUT when i create an instance to store `favorite users` from Admin before adding `favorite users` from site AND then if i add favorite users from site then they are adding. BUT if there is not already a instance of `request.user`'s FavouriteUsers in Admin then it is not adding and creating a new object.

So, A new object for storing `favorite users` of `request.user` is not adding, AND if object is already there then they are adding.

models.py

```
class FavoriteUsers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    favorite_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favorite_users', blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def AddFavUsers(request,user_id):
    obj = FavoriteUsers.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    user = get_object_or_404(User,id=user_id)

    for ob in obj:
        ob.favorite_users.add(user)
        ob.user.add(request.user)
        ob.save()

    return redirect('home')
```

[Image of already created object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNAzz.png)

When object is already , manually created then `favorite users` are adding BUT if it is not then new object is not creating.

Any help would be much Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: `obj` will return a `FavoriteUsers` object, only if that is linked to the `request.user`, in other words, you are adding the users that have already been added previously.

Comment: It is also not very clear to me why you use a `ManyToManyField` in the first place, it looks like a `Favorite` relation should be a *junction model* between `User` and `User`.

Comment: If you want to *create* a `FavoriteUsers`, you use `FavoriteUsers.objects.create(user=reque.ust)`

Comment: `For first comment` :- Then how can i create a new `object` with a new `request.user`'s ?
`For second comment` :- Should i use `profile` instead of `user` ?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, When i use `create` then it is creating only object but not adding user in it AND then i tried another time then it says :- **duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(16) already exists.** Then i used `get_or_create` then it is showing **'tuple' object has no attribute 'favorite_users'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is basically adding the `user` to all `FavoriteUser`s that are linked to the `User`. But it is not said at all that there are such `FavoriteUser`s.

We thus can construct a `FavroiteObject` with:

```
def AddFavUsers(request,user_id):
    obj = FavoriteUsers.objects.create(
        user=request.user
    )
    obj.favorite_users.add(user_id)
    # …
```

the modeling is also a bit *odd*, since we here create a third table, it makes more sense to construct a model `Favorite` with two `ForeignKey`s that thus acts as a junction table. So this should look like:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Favorite(models.Model):
    user_to = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='favorites_from'
    )
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='favorites_to'
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user_from', 'user_to'], name='favorite_only_once')
        ]
```

If you then want to make a `user_id` a favorite of the logged in user, you can work with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def AddFavUsers(request, user_id):
    Favorite.objects.create(user_from=request.user, user_to_id=user_id)
    # …
```

You can then obtain the favorite users of a user with:

```
User.objects.filter(favorites_from__user_from=my_user)
```

where *`my_user`* is the user from which you want to obtain the favorite users.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: How can i access if `request.user` is in someone's favorite user ? Suppose i am favorite user of another user then how can know if i am favorite user of another user ?

Comment: Can't i do with my previous method ? Please

Comment: @Van: the previous method will result in data duplication, large databases, and inefficient querying. You can check with the second method if `request.user` is in someones favorites with `if someone in User.objects.filter(favorites_from__user_from=request.user)`

Comment: Give me some time to check all this and implement AND i will definitely mark it .

Comment: One last question, Suppose there are `two users` **User_1** and **User_2** AND if user **User_2** added `User_1` as a favorite user then nobody can add `User_1` as favorite. How can do if a  user is added in someone's favorite user then another user can add the someone's added user ?

Comment: @Van: you simply create an extra `Favorite` object, so `Favorite.objects.create(user_from=u1, user_to=u2)` and `Favorite.objects.create(user_from=u1, user_to=u3)` thus will ensure that `u1` is following both `u2` and `u3`.

Answer (score 0):

The [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) field already handles this. You can add a favorite_users property to your User model, which will point to the User model and Django will create the connecting table. Beware of the [symmetrical](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) parameter, if you leave it out it'll be a bidirectional relation.

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    ...
    favorite_users = models.ManyToManyField("MyUser", symmetrical=False, blank=True)
```

If you still want to write the connecting model yourself, check out the [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) parameter.